# Procedural tile texture with different column width and tile lengths

Tags: node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates, shader-nodes

I'm quite new to textures in Blender and still trying to understand how to create procedural textures using nodes. I'd like to create an approximation of these tiles. There are three column widths, a small, medium, and high, and multiple varying tile lengths.
[image: tiles with three column widths and different tile heights]

I've found [Erindale on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGMyyn2FdEFcDfP1wQRh5lQ), who does amazing things, including some demonstrations with tiles. However, his stuff is way too advanced and I can't translate some of it across to my own texture.

I've tried separating the x axis and then using several modulo nodes to get three column widths, and this partially works.
[image: Blender nodes using modulo]
[image: texture with three column widths]
However, this approach produces a repeating pattern of column widths of wide, medium, narrow, but the real tile floor does not follow the same consistent pattern. I've also tried using a Voronoi noise pattern, and this produces more randomness in the pattern. It isn't exactly right, but I'm satisfied with the effect and can get it closer using the noise settings.
[image: Blender nodes with Voronoi noise]
[image: output of Voronoi texture]

I'm now trying to work out how to do the lines across to achieve the tile lengths. If I use the modulo columns as a base on the X axis, I can almost then apply a snap and less than on the axis to get alternating rows and then shift the y axis lines depending on whether they are on a 1 or 0. However, this still isn't right as I don't shift every other column, but each third one. And I can't work out how I would do it with the Voronoi texture, as I don't know how to calculate every other column.

I think I can work out the way to apply colours to the tiles once I've separated them out.

Does someone know a good way to do this, or a good source of information for a beginner on this topic?

Comment: @Robin Betts: where are you? Are you sleeping? :D